# what if other user made edit to post after edited by me

Tags: discussion, edits

I have edited some question post on stack overflow, then after some other user also made edit on that post. My question is in this case my edited will be count towards edited post by me or not. It will be counted towards to get badges related to edit post.?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on if the person has more than 2k reputation. If the person has edit privileges, his edit most likely overrid yours, unless you had edit privileges. If you do, then you got progress towards the badge.